# Laravel Route not working in ec2 Apache HTTP Server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

I've setup my laravel website at ec2 with Apache Http Server. I'm able to view the home page, but other than home page it just showing blank page with internal error (500). It work fine is my local machine.

I've change the httpd.conf document root to "/var/www/html/mywebsite/public" and change all the AllowOverride to All But it's still showing blank page with internal error (500) for other route.

i've added virtual host as below, still no luck.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mywebsite.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mywebsite/public"
  <Directory "/var/www/html/mywebsite/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My route. (which is working)

```
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
```

Other route (which is not working)

```
Route::get('thread/ViewThread', array('uses' => 'ThreadController@ToViewThread'));
```

Comment: Did you add your .htaccess ???

Comment: Are you getting any error in error_log file for internal error ?

Comment: Check you Laravel error log located in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: hi, Brute_force... i didn't get anything in error_log.

Comment: give proper permissions to your storage folder i.e 755 or 777(worst case) and to your public folder, if you still get a blank page check laravel.log under storage/logs folder

Comment: Zahan Safallwa, I've the .htaccess fille

Comment: Did you enable apache rewrite mod?